# Converting differential equation to Legendre polynomial equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

I would like to find solutions to the following 2nd order differential equation

$$(1-\mu^{2})\frac{d^{2}g}{d\mu^{2}}+l(l+1)=0,\mu=\cos\theta$$

I think there is a transformation that leads to the Legendre polynomial equation

$$\frac{d}{d\mu}\left[(1-\mu^{2})\frac{dP}{d\mu}\right]+\left[l(l+1)-\frac{m^{2}}{1-\mu^{2}}\right]P=0$$

but I cant figure out which one (I have tried $g=(1-\mu^{2})P$, but that doesnt seem to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1-\mu^{2})\frac{d^{2}g}{d\mu^{2}}+l(l+1)=0$$
This equation cannot be transformed into Legendre polynomial equation because it isn't an equation of Legendre kind. Probably there is a typo or something missing.

$$\frac{d^{2}g}{d\mu^2}= -\frac{l(l+1)}{1-\mu^2}=\frac{l(l+1)}{2(1+\mu)}+\frac{l(l+1)}{2(1-\mu)}$$
$$\frac{dg}{d\mu}=\frac{l(l+1)}{2}\ln|1+\mu|-\frac{l(l+1)}{2}\ln|1-\mu|+c_1$$
$$g(x)=\frac{l(l+1)}{2}\left( (1+\mu)\ln|1+\mu|+(1-\mu)\ln|1-\mu| \right)+c_1\mu+c_2$$